# Adding fields during runtime Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Im working on a personal project using django rest framework. Im stuck with something.
Problem is, Initially user will be adding 3 options. If user wants he can add as many options he want. All those options should be added dynamically by just pressing on "add fields".
How should my approach to this should be?

Comment: I could have misunderstood your question, but you probably want to use some kind of frontend framework for this (Vue, React, Angular, Svelte)

Comment: Need more info. Show your data model and what your DRF serializer and viewset looks like.